Which Big Commerce API rate limiting headers to use
Looking at Big Commerce's documentation there are 2 different ways of handling rate limit retrying, and I would like to know which is preferred/works;
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/start/best-practices#playing-nicely-with-the-platform - suggests using, amongst other headers, X-Rate-Limit-Time-Reset-Ms to give you the next available window for sending a request out
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/start/about#bigcommerce-specific-response-headers - suggests using X-Retry-After
One of the libraries we're using (https://github.com/getconversio/node-bigcommerce) uses the x-retry-after header, whilst another library (https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-node) seems to use x-rate-limit-time-reset-ms
Does anyone have any idea which is the preferred approach, or if I'm missing something here?
Thanks
